# Delaying header until page 2

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I have

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}\lhead{Personal Statement} \rhead{2013}
\chead{{{\bf Name}}} \lfoot{} \rfoot{\bf \thepage} \cfoot{}
```

which gives me a header on each page. How can I start this header on page two? I would like to have my title (Personal Statement) on the front page without the header.

Comment: Which document class you are using? You may use `\thispagestyle{empty}` just after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @HarishKumar: That's it. Thanks. If you write this as an answer then I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the page style for one page by issuing `\thispagestyle{empty}`. If this is for first page (title or similar), issue the command right after the `\begin{document}`.